# Page Permissions Help Need - Asking for Password 3 times

Tags: permissions, administration, access

Ok so I have a page on our team site that only Management can see so I stopped inheriting permissions and set up its own permissions, this is the structure.

User A Contribute, Limited Access
User B Contribute, Limited Access
Admin  Full Control
User C Contribute, Limited Access

Now the problem is that whenever User A B or C tried to get to the page they are asked for their password, now if they enter it it will ask again, this happens 3 timesbefore they are allowed to view the page. This happens even if they select 'remember my password'. Any ideas why this is happening?

PS: I even tried giving all of them full control but they are still getting asked about the password 3 times. This page has two document library views on it if that helps.

Thanks for any help! I'm kind of freaking out because I have no idea what is causing this.

EDIT: I have tried adding the site under trusted sites in IE but still nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when something on the page accesses data of some sort that the user does not have access to. It prompts you for credentials 3 times and then after the third time it should fail to load whatever it was trying to access because you don't actually have access, but the rest of the page loads. The item failing could be something from another SharePoint site, something from the internet, something from a file system, etc.

What I've done to troubleshoot this in the past, even though its not the most effective, is look at the same page under two different accounts - one with the problem and one without. Note anything that might be different and then investigate where these resources are located and figure out what you need to do to get them the access they need.

Comment: Or just open IE Developer Tools or FireBug and trace the network calls. This will tell you what gets a 401.

Comment: Alright well User A is part of 2 groups one which has access to this page and one which doesn't, does one take precedence? I've tried tracing using IE Developer Tools and I get the 401 from here /company/_vti_bin/lists.asmx.Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: @rjcup3 Good call! I forgot all about that.

Comment: If you have multiple levels of security on something you get the most rights granted by any of the permission levels granted. e.g. if one group gives me read another gives me contributed, and another gives me full control, I get full control.

Comment: What kind of things do you have on this page? Anything custom? Especially anything that might be utilizing the SharePoint web services / client object model, etc.?

Comment: @Tudor Check the permissions on the target list. The user doesn't have permissions to perform the necessary task on that list.

Comment: The page has 2 list views, in other words there are two lsts created somewhere else that are placed on this page by inserting an existing list. I have checked permissions for these lists and they allow these users with contribute permissions. Is there any reason that would not be enough?

Comment: Alright, figured it out! The page is styled by a CSS file which is linked from a content editor, but the library that stores the CSS file did not have any permissions for these users. So I added their group there and they are not getting promped 3 times!!! Thanks for all the help guys!! You helped me work thought this one :D

Comment: Some of my questions didn't get answered though :( so I am still trying to figure out the answers, if I do I will post back and mark them answered, otherwise I'm not too sure what to do...mark some of them answered anyways? then edit later?